# Error Message When Running Windows Powershell On Pycharm

Tags: powershell

When attempting to remove the message when running pycharm:

> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

I typed this into the PowerShell on the advice of another StackOverflow forum:

> Powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoExit

However, I now get this error when launching Pycharm:

> > Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [powershell.exe, -NoExit, -File, C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/moderator.py/venv/Scripts/activate.ps1]
> > in C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\moderator.py
>
> See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.

Does anyone know a fix to this as I am currently unable to use the terminal to run my programs?

Comment: It says "See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details". Did you do that?

Comment: It basically just repeats the error message

"INFO - #o.j.p.t.AbstractTerminalRunner - Cannot open Local Terminal
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failed to start [powershell.exe, -NoExit, -File, C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/moderator.py/venv/Scripts/activate.ps1] in C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\moderator.py "

Comment: To add, it says:
"com.pty4j.windows.conpty.LastErrorExceptionEx: CreateProcessW failed: GetLastError() returned 2: The system cannot find the file specified. "